# Powershell script to search folder delete them create a log file of it with specific data

Tags: powershell, logfile

Need to create a PowerShell script which does browses through folders E:\user, E:\Employee, E:\admin. 
If in this folder there are folders starting with CIN Or PIN and length 6 (eg:CIN123) , delete subfolders 'log' and 'Data'. eg E:\user\cinpp123\log.
 Create a log file of this in E:\logfile\ 
ex 2020-02-18 02:00 folder successfully deleted  E:\logfile\cinpp123\log 350 MB
2020-02-18 02:00 failed deleted  E:\logfile\cinpp123\Data 350 MB

Comment: so ... what have you tried? this is a "help with code problems" site, not a "write code for you" site ... [*grin*]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read the help topic: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)